# The namespace X already contains a definition for y (Error)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am posting this question due to some errors I am experiencing while following this Microsoft ASP.NET CORE MVC tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

I have created a Model class called Movie in my project. The issue is that this throws a CS0101 error and VS Code states that my namespace already has a definition for that class. When I change the class name, however, the error persists. If I remove the namespace statement, the same error occurs except for the global namespace. This error is causing other problems in my project where I try to reference the class and it's fields. All my code is available at https://github.com/Canix1417/Personal-Projects/tree/master/DotNetMVCProject/MvcMovie
A screenshot is attached as well. Thanks in advance.
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVCc0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVCc0.png)

More troubleshooting: I tried renaming the class and removing the namespace statement, neither worked as the error persisted. I've also tried searching my solution for any other place namespace MvcMovie.Models was being used to see if a Movie class was defined along with it, the search didn't return any files that defined a movie class.[!

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b Thanks for the reply! I'm looking in my .csproj file but all I see in it is a propertygroup and itemgroup within the project. Neither of which contain a list of files. Am I looking at the wrong .csproj file by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Try just restarting VS Code. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).